DC motor always on
this is my first time working with Pi and I'm trying to control a single motor (closely following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV0S_3KMj2A).
Specs are:

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+
5V DC motor
MX1508 Dual H Bridge motor driver

Problem is, as soon as I power-up the Pi, the motor turns on on its own. The only instance when it is under control is when I run my program to get it working (where I have defined start/stop instances). As soon as I KeyboardInterrupt the program, the motor starts running again.

I've been recommended to use a pull-down resistor, but it did not work.
I've tried with other GPIO pins, same result.

Wiring:

Program:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

pwr = 80
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
motor = GPIO.PWM(2, pwr)

while True:
    motor.start(pwr)


If you want help explain what YOU have tried and how it is connected. I would rather poke my eyes out than look at youtube.

Post your code and a photo of your wiring.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you try adding a short delay at the beginning of your code? If not, plz try this. If you think of using L293D instead, you can find relevant code and circuit diagram here: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2022/04/control-dc-motor-with-raspberry-pi-4-using-python.html

@CoderMike and all, kindly check the updated post for codes and wiring schematics. Thanks!

Your motor driver tutorial is on L258, but your wiring diagram seems to be MX1508. It is a bit confusing.

It is hardly surprising that the motor runs on boot.
GPIO2 has a 1.8kΩ pullup resistor intended for I²C so it will always be HIGH.
It is unclear what the unspecified device will do in this situation.

Many thanks, @Milliways. Your expertise was valuable to me.

@PrithulChaturvedi this might help https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=167734

Thanks, @jsotola! I changed my GPIO pin to a pin that was PWM compatible and it works fine now

@PrithulChaturvedi please post an answer describing what you did, so that other people can benefit from your knowledge
